# How do I insert a string in a struct that is on an hashtable

Tags: c, glib

```
typedef struct user {
    char* id; //username
    char* name;
    char* email;
    char* phone_number;
    char* birth_date;
    char* sex; // M e F
    char* passport; // e.g: LK12938
    char* country_code;
    char* address;
    char* account_creation;
    char* pay_method;
    char* account_status;
    char* voos[50];   
    int total_voos;
} User;
```

info[0] is the info that I want to insert in user2->flights and info[1] is the hash for the hashtable;
I have a if condition that decides if the hashtable exists or not, if it exists, i do the code below

```
User* user2 = g_hash_table_lookup(users_data->users_hashtable, info[1]);
                    
        user2->flights[user->total_flights] = g_strdup(info[0]);
        user2->total_flights++;
        g_hash_table_insert(users_data->users_hashtable, info[1], user2);
```

I'm having a segmentation fault when I try to add the string to my struct, the user2->total_flights++ works and I use malloc for the struct. Maybe the syntax is wrong I dont know

Comment: What is the `User` structure? What is the `flights` member? How is it initialized? What is `info`? How is `info` initialized? What happens if there's no element found and `g_hash_table_lookup` returns a null pointer? Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: `User`, `user2` `user` and `users_data->users_hashtable`... In 6 months you'll wish you'd not **used** so many variations on `user`... Try to think of more distinctive names. You'll thank yourself...